# Using Spring CrudRepository to Insert a Record Into a One-To-One Join Table With Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to insert a record into a primary table and a related joining table via one CrudRepository.save(...) method call but have been unsuccessful thus far.  I am using Oracle and SpringBoot.

Here are my two entities:

**Sandcastle Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "ROGUE", name = "SANDCASTLE")
public class Sandcastle implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sandcastleIdGenerator", schema = "ROGUE", sequenceName = "ROGUE_SEQ_NUM_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sandcastleIdGenerator")
@Column(name = "SANDCASTLE_SEQ_NUM")
private Long id;

// other fields omitted for brevity

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Waterflow waterflow;
}
```

**Waterflow Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "ROGUE", name = "WATERFLOW")
public class Waterflow implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "SANDCASTLE_SEQ_NUM")
private Long id;

// other fields omitted for brevity

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "waterflow")
private Sandcastle sandcastle;
}
```

The `CrudRepository` code looks like this:

```
// populate Waterflow list
final Waterflow waterflow = new Waterflow();

waterflow.setOtherFields(...)

// populate Sandcastle
final Sandcastle sandcastle = new Sandcastle();

sandcastle.setOtherFields(...)
sandcastle.setWaterflow(waterflow);

// insert initial record into the Rogue schema
final Sandcastle sandcastle = this.sandcastleRepository.save();
```

Now as far as my database structure goes, the SANDCASTLE table has a primary key called SANDCASTLE_SEQ_NUM along with other columns that aren't relevant here.  And the WATERFLOW table has a foreign key to the SANDCASTLE table also called SANDCASTLE_SEQ_NUM along with other non-relevant columns; this column is also a primary key.  Essentially there's a one-to-one between SANDCASTLE and WATERFLOW. In other words, an insert in the SANDCASTLE table will always result in an insert in the WATERFLOW table.  Also, there is indeed an Oracle sequence on the SANDCASTLE id field called `ROGUE_SEQ_NUM_SEQ`.

Now upon executing the `save` method above I receive the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.whatever.something.Waterflow
```

A few other things I tried:

- changing the `GenerationType` from `SEQUENCE` to `AUTO`, but received the same `IdentifierGenerationException`.
- Adding the `@SequenceGenerator` and `@GeneratedValue` annotations to the Waterflow Entity as well (trying both `SEQUENCE` and `AUTO`); in that case I receive this error:  `Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ROGUE.WATERFLOW_FK0) violated parent key not found`

I realize what the errors are stating, but what I'd like Hibernate to do is intelligently insert the generated id of the SANDCASTLE table as the id of the WATERFLOW table upon that single `save`.  Is that possible...and if so what do I need to change to make that happen?

Comment: Maybe you want to use rather this annotation  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

Comment: Maybe you should use @ SequenceGenerator and @ GeneratedValue for WaterFlow entity also.

Comment: @lewa9 - Changing the type to `AUTO` yields the same error.  @Sujay Mohan - adding those annotations to the WATERFLOW table as well (whether both of type `SEQUENCE` or `AUTO`) yields a different error.  I will update that in the question above.  Also, there is indeed a sequence in the Oracle database associated with the SANDCASTLE table; I'll add that to the question as well for clarity.